# Parent controls lose manipulation features when child controls ManipulationMode is set to other than 'None'

Tags: c#, windows-runtime

Basically, I have a `SemanticZoom` control with a `GridView` inside it, and the `GridView` has a custom control inside it, but for simplicity, let's assume it's a simple red `Border`. The problem is that I'm trying to handle the Border's manipulation when scaling (set `ManipulationMode` to `Scale`) so that I can know when the user does a pinch out gesture and "Zoom In" into the Border (which is really another page), but by handling the Manipulation, I lose the ability to (1) use the SemanticZoom and (2) Scrolling the grid.

If you have used the Windows 8 photo app, you'll notice that they implement this feature somehow. If you pinch in into an image, the Page will go into SemanticZoom, but if you pinch out it will go into full screen mode. I want similar functionality, but I don't know how to achieve it.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I will use 2 SemanticZoom controls to achieve Photo App Effect.